# Let F be a field and let $A,B ∈M_{n×n}(F)$ be a commuting pair of matrices, where B is nonsingular. Is $(A,B^{−1})$ necessarily a commuting pair?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I´m trying to solve this problem, but I can´t, I don´t know how to start.

Let F be a field and let $A,B ∈M_{n×n}(F)$ be a commuting pair of matrices,
where B is nonsingular. Is $(A,B^{−1})$ necessarily a commuting pair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  We have $$ AB = BA \implies B^{-1}(AB)B^{-1} = B^{-1}(BA)B^{-1} \implies B^{-1}A = AB^{-1}. $$